# Viewbag variable in shared view _layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to use ViewBag values in the shared view of layout but provided from another controller. In particular, I would like to render the principal action and then add few variables, coming from another controller, that are used in a lot of pages (but not in all pages to justify the use of global variables).

Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css_custom")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Action("myAction", "myController")

    <p>Value: @ViewBag.testval </p>

    @RenderBody()

</body>
</html>
```

Controllers/myController.cs

```
namespace myProject.Controllers
{
    public class myController : Controller
    {

        public void myAction() {

            string test_value = "Hey!";

            ViewBag.testval = test_value;
        }

    }

}
```

In the layout the only Viewbag variables that I can access are the ones of the action target of RenderBody.

Comment: If you do not pass the values to the view, then how would you expect to access them (what are you expecting to happen)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand... But how to add new variables to ViewBag coming from another controller?

Comment: You cant, you need to add them in the controller that is generating the view.

Comment: Why work with a viewbag when you can make a basemodel which the models who need the `testval` should derrive and the basemodel has the testval string. I am looking forward to your solution. And why you chose that option.

Answer (score 0):

You should return that view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.testval = "Test value";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I don't need a page, I need only some variables.

Comment: So use json or something else (ajax call with javascript callback). MVC actions run on server side, so your view does not refresh view bag, because you use void method that does not return anything to client.